# Send files between two online servers?

Tags: windows-7, internet, remote, storage, cloud

Is there a tool which I can user to send files between two remote servers? For example, I have hosting at hostgator and I create a directory there. Then I use that tool to send files from some other remote storage to that directory.

I want to skip the step of downloading files to my computer and uploading it to another storage.

Comment: Could look into something like dropbox. You can sync a folder between two computers, or three if you don't want to connect to each one. Though I don't know how viable this would be because I'm not sure of the policies you have about installing software on the servers. But it would work.

Comment: What kind of access do you have to the server? Shell access? Root access?

Comment: @Dennis On hostgator hosting I have shell access, while other server is just a path access (direct URL).

Comment: @Paperlantern Dropbox cannot work as I cannot download remote files directly onto it

Comment: Do you want to move files from or to the hostgator server? How do you upload files to the other server? Web-based? FTP?

Comment: @stnrower Ah, yeah I was afraid of that, that is unfortunate.

Comment: @Paperlantern Files on other servers are upload by some other people via ftp or similar. I want to move files TO hostgator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily and securely be done using the `SSH` protocol. With [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) you can connect to your remote host with a shell and tranfer files using `scp`:

```
$ scp -r foo_dir user@foo.org:server_dir/
```

this will copy `foo_dir` from your connected server to another server `foo.org` into the directory `server_dir` there.
To copy from `foo.org` to the connected server:

```
$ scp -r user@foo.org:server_dir/foo_dir ./
```

Comment: I will definitely try this tomorrow.

Comment: @krondor Thanks for reminding me of `user@`.

Answer (score 3):

Reading your comments it's clear you have the following scenario.

- Shell Access to one server
- No Access other than URL to the other server

In this case I think your solution would be;

**Wget**

If you have the Wget command available to you from the Shell of the first server you can specify the URL to fetch the content from the second server.  You can also pass parameters on what content you wish to get (or even fully mirror from the other system).

[Lifehacker has a good write up on using Wget](http://lifehacker.com/161202/geek-to-live--mastering-wget)

Outside of Wget there are quite a few options depending on your host and host access.

Are the servers Linux (or Unix like)?

In the case of Windows **RDP** is an option.  The RDP client can provide native file transfers between hosts.  To initiate this you would RDP to one of the servers and then from that server RDP to the other server configuring file transfer options before hand.

To configure the file transfer abilities;

```
    Run the Remote Desktop Connection.
    Enter the IP address of the computer you want to connect to.
    Click Options and go to the Local Resources to Select the box for Disk Drives and connect/logon to the remote Windows computer.
    Open Windows Explorer. You'll notice additional hard drives (x on tsclient) that represent the hard drives on the local computer.
    Copy the files between the local and remote computer by dragging and dropping the files in Windows Explorer.
```

**Rsync:**  Sync delta changes, supports compression, bandwidth throttling, works over SSH or client/daemon, cross platform (Windows Client/Server available).  Rsync has a similar syntax to SCP, but with more bells and whistles on control of the copy.

Example:

```
    rsync /folder1/ user@host2.example.com:/folder1/
```

**SCP:**  Already mentioned in another answer.  Works over SSH, supports compression and recursion.

Example:

```
    scp -r /folder1/ user@host2.example.com:/folder1/
```

In the case of both RSync and SCP you will need to shell into one of the servers to initiate the command.  If you initiate the command from your workstation with both hosts specified (scp user@host1:/folder1 user@host2:/folder2) it will transfer through that workstation which is not what you want.

**FXP:**

Lastly (but not really recommended), you could use [FTP's File eXchange Protocol (FXP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) which is a subset of the FTP protocol to remotely initiate an FTP transfer between two servers.  The file transferred would be direct from server to server and not to your initiating connection.

To do so would open you up to a security risk of an FTP Bounce Attack, however, and is usually discouraged.  If that risk is acceptable for your purposes (maybe you can adequately firewall between both hosts), than in order to proceed you will need two things.

1. An FXP compatible FTP server ([Pure-FTPd](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd) works)
2. An FXP compatible FTP client ([FlashFXP](http://www.flashfxp.com/) is one)

Comment: A few edits mainly to add wget after reading your comments, add RDP when I saw the windows 7 tag, and correct a mistake I made on scp/rsync and where you would be running that from.

Comment: +1 - Excellent answer that goes over all the options.

Answer (score 0):

Create an FTP session. Are you allowed to FTP from HostGator to another source? For instance, on HostMonster I have multiple FTP session options including the ability to FTP from my Hostmonster account to another source (not just my local machine).

You should see the option in your cpanel.

Comment: I will check this up, but I am really not sure. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: This requires the client *and* both servers to have "FXP" support enabled; most servers disable it due to security issues.

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to the FTP account manager, create ftp accounts for the 2 servers then goto https://www.multcloud.com

You can follow their guide here, but you really don't have to, their system is very straight forward

http://kunmii.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-easily-migrate-your-website.html

Comment: This looks a bit like spam. Can you state whether you're affiliated with the developer of this service?

Comment: Nope, I'm not, but I make use of their service, occasionally.